# Aggregation on nested data set

Tags: nosql

I'm trying to write an aggregation in Mongo which would result as shown below:
Please Suggest me how to build Mongo Aggregation in order to achieve my output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$module.module_details.data" //Reshape
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$module.module_child.data" //Reshape
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        "$eq": [ //Get the matched data
          "$module.module_child.data.module_child_id",
          "$module.module_details.data.module_child_id"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$_id",
      data: { //group again
        $push: {
          "k": "$module.module_child.data.name",
          "v": "$module.module_details.data.value"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": { //Reshape the data
      _id: 1,
      child: {
        "$arrayToObject": "$data"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6FxzyoXWPg0)

You can add another `$project` to get the desired shape.